Permission denied when I Install Laravel UI
In RequireCommand.php line 155:

file_put_contents(C:\Users\USER\composer\bin): Failed to open stream: Permission denied

When I try to install Laravel UI, I encounter a permission denied error. Can you help me with this?
I was expecting the Laravel UI installation process to proceed smoothly without any errors. However, I encountered a 'permission denied' error during the installation. I'm unsure why this error occurred and how to resolve it. Can you assist me in troubleshooting and fixing this issue?
Thanks in advance.

It clearly means that composer does not have permissions to write to the specified directory. ensure composer has permission to write to that directory.

Which command do you execute? Writing stuff to the file you've mentioned does not look like a common access

Thank you, everyone. I changed the composer path in the environment variables. With these changes, I was able to correct my problem.
